# Should I delete my comment from a question if the question is updated?

Tags: discussion, questions, comments, deleted-comments

Recently an OP posted [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33885514/multiplying-a-array-times-2#33885514) without any information by which we can help him, so I added a comment:

> Your provided information in question does not help us to help you. kindly come with code and error.

Now, after some time, the code and other information is updated in the question. So, should I delete my comment or is it fine to leave it as it is? Now, anyone who comes on that question will feel like all the information is there even though I have commented like this.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If your comment is no longer relevant to the question, then yes, you should delete it. You suggested that OP should add code and a description of the error, which they did. Your comment is no longer necessary. So, yes, you can delete that comment.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot for clarification.

Comment: @HelpingHands if you're that conscientious about keeping things tidy - there's also a comment you could have flagged as obsolete as well :)

Comment: @JonClements - Wow ,Thanks for letting me know. I was not properly aware about use of that flag.. thanks again.

Comment: @JonClements, if i see obsolete comment in some old post, should i flag it (very quick for me) or leave it as is to avoid wasting moderator time?

Comment: @ASh if you happen to find such comments while naturally browsing the site then by all means feel free to flag them.

Comment: @JonClements, thank you for clarification. yes, i do not search them on purpose. just coincidence when i am looking for an answer to my current issue

Answer (score 6):

Generally speaking, comments are fleeting things. They are there to request clarification or discuss question or answer relevant things as a part of the process of fleshing out an answer/question and correcting inaccuracies.

There is no shame in deleting your own comments if they are no longer relevant.

Further, there is no shame or implied wrondoing if your comment gets flagged as obsolete and deleted. This also holds true for comments you flag as obsolete. Neither of those things imply wrongdoing.

The community consensus seems to be to remove comments that no longer mean anything.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should delete the comment on that question as it is becoming the meaningless.

Sometimes it may be happen that some user have posted questions with less details or lack of necessary details. So surely you will ask for the full details. Now when the questioner provide the full detail, you may delete the comment as there is no necessary of the comment.